# rxjs return Observable (typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular2

Добрый день, решил попробовать rxjs, однако, не очень могу понять как снять получившиеся данные из Observable:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from  "rxjs/Rx";
@Injectable()
export class ServiceProvider {
  combined:any;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    Observable.forkJoin(
      this.http.get('data/data0.json').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
      this.http.get('data/data1.json').map((res:Response) => res.json())
    ).subscribe(res => this.combined = res);
    console.log(this.combined);
  }
}
```

Вот небольшой класс, в результате работы должен выйти массив с упакованыыми данными из двух разных запросов. Однако, в конечном итоге приходит undefined.
Я так понимаю, что необходимо выхватывать какое-то событие или еще что-то. Но своим умом понять не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from  "rxjs/Rx";
@Injectable()
export class ServiceProvider {
  combined:any;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    let self = this;
    Observable.forkJoin(
      this.http.get('data/data0.json').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
      this.http.get('data/data1.json').map((res:Response) => res.json())
    ).subscribe(res => {
        self.combined = res;
        console.log(self.combined);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, так работает, но как, к примеру сделать return этого combined
Чтоб получилось
loadData(){
...
return combined
}

Comment: @SoSlow Немного поменял ответ.

Comment: @SoSlow Обычно сервис должен возвратить готовый Observable, а клиентские классы вызывают для этого сервиса subscribe